# Traduction de « a rundown on the sub and a précis of the stuff in your hand » : choix de mots et formulation ?

Tags: traduction, anglais, synonymes, formulation, coordination

> *Just give him a [rundown](https://learnersdictionary.com/definition/rundown) on the sub 
>  and a [précis](https://learnersdictionary.com/definition/pr%C3%A9cis) of the stuff in
> your hand.*
>
> ---

> Fais un topo général.

> *The Hunt for the Red October* (1990), McTiernan, d'après l'oeuvre de Tom Clancy ; extrait de sous-titres à 00:34:54.

Le contexte est que l'analyste à qui l'on fait cette demande vient d'être informé de l'existence possible d'un système de propulsion silencieux d'un sous-marin balistique russe et est en train de lire un rapport provenant d'un sous-marin américain patrouillant la côte Est qui aurait vu un sous-marin « disparaître » devant lui, ainsi que des informations sur le déploiement de bâtiments de la marine russe qui filent maintenant à toute allure vers l'Atlantique Nord.

Entre la traduction présentée ou une autre qui s'appuierait par exemple sur la coordination d'un nom à deux termes (*nom* de *sous-marin* et *informations dont on dispose*) et encore une autre qui emploierait comme en anglais deux compléments pour deux noms coordonnés, laquelle préfèrerait-on et pourquoi et quel terme ou doublet de termes emploierait-on selon le cas ?

Comment: *Topo* pour le constat  et *résumé* pour l'analyse.

Comment: Ah, le vote négatif « aléatoire » !

Comment: « *aléatoire* » n'empêche pas de justifier … tout cela mérite le mépris :-)